# How to deploy app in cloudfoundry running on vagrant using bosh-lite?

Tags: linux, vagrant, cloud-foundry, devops, bosh-deployer

I am to trying to deploy application in cloud foundry which is running on my local vagrant machine.I have deployed CF using bosh lite.

```
vagrant@bosh-lite:~$ bosh vms
Acting as user 'admin' on 'Bosh Lite Director'
Deployment `cf-warden'

Director task 40

Task 40 done

+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------+
| Job/index                          | State              | Resource Pool | IPs          |
+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------+
| api_z1/0                           | unresponsive agent | large_z1      |              |
| consul_z1/0                        | unresponsive agent | small_z1      |              |
| doppler_z1/0                       | unresponsive agent | medium_z1     |              |
| etcd_z1/0                          | unresponsive agent | medium_z1     |              |
| ha_proxy_z1/0                      | unresponsive agent | router_z1     |              |
| hm9000_z1/0                        | unresponsive agent | medium_z1     |              |
| loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1/0 | running            | small_z1      | 10.244.0.146 |
| nats_z1/0                          | unresponsive agent | medium_z1     |              |
| postgres_z1/0                      | unresponsive agent | medium_z1     |              |
| router_z1/0                        | unresponsive agent | router_z1     |              |
| runner_z1/0                        | unresponsive agent | runner_z1     |              |
| uaa_z1/0                           | unresponsive agent | medium_z1     |              |
+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------+

VMs total: 12
```

When i am trying to set target i am getting the following issue ::

```
vagrant@bosh-lite:~$ cf api --skip-ssl-validation https://api.10.244.0.146.xip.io
Setting api endpoint to https://api.10.244.0.146.xip.io...
FAILED
Error performing request: Get https://api.10.244.0.146.xip.io/v2/info: dial tcp 10.244.0.146:443: connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the jobs (api_z1/0, etc) are not operational in that deployment. All of them should be in "running" state. Please try the cloud check command by running "bosh cck" and see if you can recover them.

Once you have them up and running, try instead: "cf api https://api.bosh-lite.com --skip-ssl-validation"